# VBA Horizontal Scrolling Not Working In Coding Window

Tags: excel, vba, scroll, office365, scrollbar

Just a quick question.

I am unable to horizontally (left to right) scroll using either my; touchpad or mouse, within the VBA coding window at all. Manually selecting the scroll bar works fine, I am just unable to use the touchpad or a external mouse. Horizontal scrolling works in every other program and in Windows, just not in VBA. :(

I have tried both online and offline repairs of office, as well as reimagining the system using both the OME (Dell) image and then also a Image directly from Microsoft.

If anyone has any ideas or imput all all, it would be greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say *manually* what do you mean? Don't you still use the mouse to grab the scrollbar and scroll?

Comment: By that I guess I mean: using the touchpad and moving my mouse cursor, selecting the horizontal scroll bar and moving that way does work. I just can't use my touchpad scrolling or a USB mouse scroll wheel.